# Event detect when css property changed using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to detect if the "display" css property of an element is changed (to whether none or block or inline-block...)? if not, any plugin? Thanks

Answer (score 94, accepted):

> #### Note
>
> [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) have been deprecated since this post was written, and may not be supported by all browsers. Instead, use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Yes you can. DOM L2 Events module defines [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents); one of them - **DOMAttrModified** is the one you need. Granted, these are not widely implemented, but are supported in at least Gecko and Opera browsers.

Try something along these lines:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', function(e){
  if (e.attrName === 'style') {
    console.log('prevValue: ' + e.prevValue, 'newValue: ' + e.newValue);
  }
}, false);

document.documentElement.style.display = 'block';
```

You can also try utilizing [IE's "propertychange" event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956%28VS.85%29.aspx) as a replacement to `DOMAttrModified`. It should allow to detect `style` changes reliably.

Comment: Thanks. Will it support Firefox ?

Comment: Yes, IIRC, FF2 and up to a current one.

Comment: This won't work if the effective CSS display property for an element is changed indirectly; for example, by changing the CSS class of the element.

Comment: @Tim Down: In that case the event is still fired. You have to watch for modification of `@class` and can use getComputedStyle afterwards.

Comment: @Boldewyn: True, but changing the `class` attribute (or any other attribute if attribute selectors are present in the CSS) of an ancestor of the element could also change the element, so you'd have to handle all `DOMAttrModified` events on the document root element to be sure of catching everything.

Comment: That event is deprecated in w3c. It must be another way.

Comment: The mutation events have been marked as deprecated in the DOM Events specification, as the API's design is flawed. Mutation Observers are the proposed replacement. Here's the link [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events]

Comment: A great replacement for `DOM*` is [`animationStart` and some CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13835369/237285).

Comment: Anmol - the MDN link for Mutation events should be: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Comment: @kangax. Can you help me on this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429746/dont-lose-previous-position-of-rzslider-after-select-the-date-in-angular-js?noredirect=1#comment77835931_45429746

Comment: @kangax. I've updated your answer to reflect the current state of affairs. Although valid at the time, I wouldn't recommend using mutation events nowadays.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [attrchange jQuery plugin](http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/). The main function of the plugin is to bind a listener function on attribute change of HTML elements.

Code sample:

```
$("#myDiv").attrchange({
    trackValues: true, // set to true so that the event object is updated with old & new values
    callback: function(evnt) {
        if(evnt.attributeName == "display") { // which attribute you want to watch for changes
            if(evnt.newValue.search(/inline/i) == -1) {

                // your code to execute goes here...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that for some plugins that modify CSS evnt.attributeName is 'style' not 'display'.

Comment: Works well but this is faster than using regex search and you don't need the first if(evnt.attributeName...): if  (evnt.newValue.indexOf('display: inline-block') > -1) { ...; return;}

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery's `css` function to test the CSS properties, eg. `if ($('node').css('display') == 'block')`.

Colin is right, that there is no explicit event that gets fired when a specific CSS property gets changed. But you may be able to flip it around, and trigger an event that sets the display, and whatever else.

Also consider using adding CSS classes to get the behavior you want. Often you can add a class to a containing element, and use CSS to affect all elements. I often slap a class onto the body element to indicate that an AJAX response is pending. Then I can use CSS selectors to get the display I want.

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

For properties for which css transition will affect, can use transitionend event, example for z-index:

```js
$(".observed-element").on("webkitTransitionEnd transitionend", function(e) {
  console.log("end", e);
  alert("z-index changed");
});

$(".changeButton").on("click", function() {
  console.log("click");
  document.querySelector(".observed-element").style.zIndex = (Math.random() * 1000) | 0;
});
```

```css
.observed-element {
  transition: z-index 1ms;
  -webkit-transition: z-index 1ms;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="changeButton">change z-index</button>
<div class="observed-element"></div>
```

Answer (score -21):

You can't. CSS does not support "events". Dare I ask what you need it for? Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329621/jquery-detect-change-in-class-assignment) here on SO. I can't think of a reason why you would want to hook up an event to a style change. I'm assuming here that the style change is triggered somwhere else by a piece of javascript. Why not add extra logic there?

Comment: I have several events that can trigger a box to appear or not. And I have another element that kinda depends on the appearance of that box to do things. Now, I don't want to repeat code and hook up to all other events making appearance to the box although that is one way to do it. Just redundance!

Comment: It is redundant, maybe using a rule based system would work? ie, some JSON like structure that defines what should happen to some control when another control changes? this way you would only need to create 1 function tht uses the rule object and perhaps the current control(id) as parameter?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Defining class for the parent of both elements and changing style on it is the only right solution for this.

Comment: Downvoted for "I can't think of a reason why you would want to hook up an event to a style change" - if you can't think of a reason it doesn't mean there is no possible reason, and for "Why not add extra logic there?" - because you can't always modify the scripts.

Comment: To provide an example, I want to change the fill property of an svg path when the colour property of the parent element changes.