# DOM mutation events replacement

Tags: html, events, dom, dom3, mutation-events

Since DOM mutation is marked as deprecated by the w3c (see http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents), is there an (fast) alternative way to detect attribute modification in the DOM ?

Comment: You can even consider John Resig's NodeList - https://github.com/jeresig/nodelist However, this is still in development phases, but seems promising candidate as a replacement to the mutation events.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know there is no alternative (yet) so you are stuck with `DOMAttrModified` which is only supported in Firefox and Opera. In IE you have the `onpropertychanged` event but there is no way to get similar functionality in Chrome/Safari. There are a number of things you could do depending on what you are trying to accomplish and the browsers you are targetting:

- define getters and setters to the attributes you want to monitor
- override methods like `document.createAttribute`, `attributes.setNamedItem`, ...

I've been working on a cross-browser solution myself but without much success. You should stay away from mutation events all together since they are not cross-browser and very slow.
There are good reasons why they are deprecated. If you want to learn more read this:

- http://www.w3.org/2008/webapps/wiki/MutationReplacement
- http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/ > W3C events
- http://robertnyman.com/javascript/javascript-getters-setters.html

Comment: I think the Mozilla guys [finished your work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13835369/237285). :)

Answer (score 31):

The reason that mutation events was deprecated was because of huge performance issues.

The replacement is **Mutation Observers**, look at http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers

Information about mutations is delivered to observers as an ordered sequence of MutationRecords, representing an observed sequence of changes that have occurred

Sample usage:

```
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationRecords) {
    // Handle mutations
     });

    observer.observe(myNode,
     {  // options:
     subtree: true,  // observe the subtree rooted at myNode
     childList: true,  // include information childNode insertion/removals
     attribute: true  // include information about changes to attributes within the subtree
    });
```

This is supported in Chrome 18 and Firefox and Webkit nightly builds. Firefox 14 will also be supporting this feature.

Comment: Those semicolons in the 'options' object literal should be commas.

Answer (score 13):

A great replacement for the deprecated DOM* events is `animationStart` in conjunction with CSS Animations. [David Walsh writes](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion) about the method.

First, set up the keyframes and apply it to the elements you'd like to listen for (**don't forget the vendor prefixes!**):

```
@keyframes nodeInserted {  
  from { clip: rect(1px, auto, auto, auto); }
  to { clip: rect(0px, auto, auto, auto); }  
}

#parentElement > li {
  animation-duration: 0.001s;
  animation-name: nodeInserted;
}
```

Next, add the listener:

```
var insertListener = function(event){
  if (event.animationName == "nodeInserted") {
    // This is the debug for knowing our listener worked!
    // event.target is the new node!
    console.warn("Another node has been inserted! ", event, event.target);
  }
}
document.addEventListener("animationstart", insertListener, false); // standard + firefox
document.addEventListener("MSAnimationStart", insertListener, false); // IE
document.addEventListener("webkitAnimationStart", insertListener, false); // Chrome + Safari
```

Ta-da! Here is [David's demo](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/detect-node-insertion.php). It works great for me on a Chrome extension that [adds Facebook pictures to Google Voice](https://github.com/ariofrio/gvoice-facebook-pictures) (see content.css and injected.js).

Comment: BTW. `clip:rect` doesn't trigger events in IE10. I got it fixed some time ago

Answer (score 12):

**A year later**, there are the new and shiny [`Mutation Observers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers) from DOM Level 4 (follow the links there, they explain a lot!). Where a `Mutation Event` fired a thousand times, `MutationObserver` fires only once with all the modifications contained and accessible.

Works for (as of 2017/03):

- Firefox 14+
- IE 11
- Edge
- Opera 15+
- Chrome 26+ (18 till 25 prefixed, `window.WebKitMutationObserver`)
- Safari 6.0 (prefixed, `window.WebKitMutationObserver`)