# Detecting DOM change events

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, nodes, mutation-events

Is there a way to detect DOM change events?  whether it be text replacement, moving a node, removing or adding a new node, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [`DOMSubtreeModified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference)

**Edit:** upon further inspection this and other `MutationEvents` have been [deprecated by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified) but there doesn't appear to be a [replacement until DOM Level 4](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutation-observers)

See: ["Why is the DOMSubtreeModified event deprecated in DOM level 3?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3)

Long story short, `DOMSubtreeModified` will still work and there is no reasonable alternative implemented across stable browsers.

Comment: You can use [`animationStart` and some CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13835369/237285) to achieve the same effect on modern, stable browsers.

Comment: Nine years later, [`MutationObserver`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3219767/157247) is the stable, well-supported way to do this.