# Detecting when DOM has change value of input continuously

Tags: javascript

So, I have an input bar that I want to continuously search if it's been modified. I checked some stackoverflow questions like [Detecting DOM change events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733306/detecting-dom-change-events) and I checked this DOMSubTreeModified thing.

It works the first time, but I need to continuously check if there's been an update. Is there a way to loop it?

Comment: duplicate question: See any of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=detect+input+change

Answer (score 3):

You can use timeintervals:

```
var oldVal = document.getElementById("yourInput").value;
function check(){
    if(document.getElementById("yourInput").value !== oldVal){
        alert("value changed");
    }
}

setInterval(check, 1000);
```

Code should be self explanatory :)

Or you could bind change or input events (but they should not work if you change value with javascript). Sorry using jQuery in this example :)

```
$("#yourInput").on("change input", function(event){
    alert("value changed")
});
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "change input" event. There is `change`, but that only gets fired when the input is blurred.

Comment: If you don't know better dont say anything. You can check it on google. Only problem that input event is not supported in IE<9

Comment: @VytautasButkus - Please provide a link.  I'm not finding anything on google.

Comment: uhm, yeah, that's the `change` event that @MichaelMior referred to.  `change input` isn't a real thing.

Comment: @broofa Wow, now you are really stupid. I give you link with information about event existance. You can event try it on Stackoverflow(just open console) $("input").first().on("input", function(){console.log("i really work")})
And you still speak nonsense?
Change event doesn't capture paste'ing or draging text into box and input captures it all.
Check before speaking.

Comment: Just realized that the confusion here is that jquery will accept a space-separated list of event names for it's first argument.

Comment: @VytautasButkus You're absolutely right, so thanks for the clarification. But such a hostile tone and calling people stupid is not welcome on SO.

Comment: I'm really sorry for that(my apologies @broofa) but just couldn't hold my self after I give reference and people say that it's nonsense :)

Comment: @VytautasButkus Thanks :) My initial remark wasn't meant to be insulting, but it's hard to be concise in writing and not come off sounding a little rude. I had completely forgotten about space delimited events in jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a change in value of an `input` tag? In that case, you're not talking about the DOM being changed. Try the `onKeyDown` event handler.

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  // Perform search
});
```

Comment: doesn't capture subtle forms of changes, such as user selecting a substring and using mouse to drag selection to different part of input.