# How to stop yahoo changing "href" to "dirtyhref" when I click a link?

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I'm a chinese internet user. Google/Yahoo search engines are very unstable in my country.
When I click a yahoo search result link, I often get this error page:

```
ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved    
While trying to retrieve the URL: http://search.yahoo.com/r/_ylt=A0oGdUY7FbNQFQsA5rZXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTE0ODJ2YTduBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMQRjb2xvA3NrMQR2dGlkA1ZJUDA1MV83Ng--/SIG=11ac0sa5q/EXP=1353942459/**http%3a//www.google.com/

The following error was encountered:    
    Access Denied.    
    Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect. 

Your cache administrator is noc_admin@163.com.
by DXT-GZ-APP02
```

I notice that yahoo will change the value of `href` to `dirtyhref` automatically when I click a link.
I try to `$('a[id|=link]').unbind('click mousedown')`, but it doesn't work.
How to stop yahoo doing it?

---

Currently, I use this firefox greasemonkey code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Clean URL
// @namespace   http://hjkl.me
// @include     https://www.google.com/search*
// @include     http://search.yahoo.com/search*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

// GOOGLE
$('h3.r>a').removeAttr('onmousedown');

// YAHOO
$('a[id|=link]').on('click', function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('dirtyhref').split('**')[1];
    url = decodeURIComponent(url);
    $(this).attr('href', url);  //<-- yahoo will change it back!
    window.open(url, '_blank');
    return false;
});
```

The problem is: I cannot use the middle-mouse-click function. (Open tabpage silently)

Comment: Change it back manually?

Comment: When I change it back, yahoo will change it back again.

Comment: Do you open the links in a separate window (no navigation) or in the search window (changed when navigating back)?

Comment: What if you _clone_ the `dirtyhref` into `href`?

Comment: Why are you even trying to prevent the change? The new value of `href` is still usable.

Comment: The page javascript is minified, but you can still attempt debbuging (and so shall I). The pretty print functionality of the Chrome console really helps.

Comment: yahoo will change the `href` every time I click it.

Comment: Then why don't you bind to the click event?

Comment: firefox middle-mouse-click to open tabpage sliently will make use of `href`. But I cannot change it to a `un-dirtyhref`. This is the problem

Comment: I'm afraid you have to find out _when_ Yahoo changes the attribute, and change it back. Hold on, I think there's an event for that.

Comment: Do you accept a firefox-only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9+, Opera and Firefox define the [`DOMAttrModified`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdchxcl.php) event. Sadly, current versions of Webkit do not define this event.

This will override the `href` attribute of `a[id|=link]` to the value of `dirtyhref` whenever any of its attributes change. Note that assigning an attribute its current value does not count as a change:

```
$('a[id|=link]').on('DOMAttrModified', function(){
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("dirtyhref"));
});
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/ZzJae/

You also need to override the links on page load.

If new links may appear continuously (say, AutoPager is present), you may also need to bind [`DOMNodeInserted`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php) and use event delegation: `$(document).on("DOM...", "a[id|=link]", handler)`

IE9+, Chrome+Safari and Firefox define [`DOMSubtreeModified`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php), but Opera doesn't. If you want to add Webkit support, you will need to listen to this event as well.

A sketch of the final solution (firefox only):

```
(function(){
  function overrideOne(){
    var dirty = $(this).attr("dirtyhref");
    var clean = dirty.split("**")[1];
    $(this).attr("href", clean);
  }
  function overrideAll(){
    $("a[id|=link]").each(overrideOne)
  }

  $(document).on("ready DOMNodeInserted", overrideAll);
  $(document).on("DOMAttrChanged", "a[id|=link]", overrideOne);
  $(document).on("click", "a[id|=link]",function(){
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: [Mutation events are deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents).  This approach will be buggy, and tend to suck up CPU cycles and memory.  (And it will not work with some future release of FF.)

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks for the link. Note that it _only_ says the `MutationEvent` interface is deprecated - the events themselves seem to stay, at least until DOM4 is introduced. I don't use the interface (perhaps I should?), I only listen to the events.

Comment: The events are part of the MutationEvent interface; they are obsoleted along with it.  [Mutation Observers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11106031/331508) are the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, people just copy the "good" `href` value to the bad/tracking `dirtyhref` attribute and then let Yahoo do it's thing.

Nowadays, just sanitize both values.

Here's an AJAX-handling script that seems to work for me:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Clean URL
// @namespace   http://hjkl.me
// @include     http://search.yahoo.com/search*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

// GOOGLE
$('h3.r>a').removeAttr('onmousedown');

// YAHOO
waitForKeyElements ("a[id|=link]", fixDirtyLinks);

function fixDirtyLinks (jNode) {
    var url = jNode.attr('dirtyhref').split('**');
    if (url.length > 1) {
        var goodURL = decodeURIComponent (url[1]);
        jNode.attr ('href', goodURL);
        jNode.attr ('dirtyhref', goodURL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you need to do is remove the `dirtyhref` attribute. In order to prevent `href` from becoming dirty, your `dirtyhref` removal function has to run before Yahoo!'s function. To do this, use event capturing with the mouse events.

Here is my user JS that I use in Opera:

Disable Yahoo! Search rewrite:

https://gist.github.com/XP1/5008515/

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Disable Yahoo! Search rewrite
// @version 1.00
// @description Disables the rewrite of links in Yahoo! Search results.
// @namespace https://gist.github.com/XP1/5008515/
// @copyright 2013
// @author XP1
// @homepage https://github.com/XP1/
// @license Apache License, Version 2.0; http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
// @include http*://search.yahoo.*/search?*
// @include http*://*.search.yahoo.*/search?*
// ==/UserScript==

/*
 * Copyright 2013 XP1
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

/*jslint browser: true, vars: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4 */
(function (window, MouseEvent, HTMLElement) {
    "use strict";

    function disableRewrite(event) {
        if (!(event instanceof MouseEvent)) {
            return;
        }

        var target = event.target;

        var current = null;
        for (current = target; current instanceof HTMLElement; current = current.parentNode) {
            if (current.hasAttribute("dirtyhref")) {
                current.removeAttribute("dirtyhref");
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("mousedown", disableRewrite, true);
    window.addEventListener("click", disableRewrite, true);
}(this, this.MouseEvent, this.HTMLElement));
```