# window onload event not fired in chrome content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I use content script in my Chrome extension. content scripts are injected at "document_start".

```
window.onload = function() {console.log("window onload event fired.");}
```

I run the above code in content script, but when I load a page, the onload event is not fired.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: can you share your manifest file?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917047/how-to-get-a-content-script-to-load-after-a-pages-javascript-has-executed

Answer (score 3):

Check with this Code

```
if (window.attachEvent) {window.attachEvent('onload', your_function);}
else if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('load', your_function, false);}
else {document.addEventListener('load', your_function, false);}
```

Comment: there's no `window.attachEvent` in Chrome. For chrome `window.addEventListener` is all you need.

Answer (score -2):

It's working perfectly.In order to check whether the `console.log` is fired or not on windows onload event.

Run(`Load`) the Page/Script in Chrome.

`Right click` and select `Inspect element`.

Click on `Console tab`.

You will see "`window onload event fired.`" on console box.

**Screen Shot:**

[image]

Comment: Also can you be a little more specific.Does windows onload event not fired at all? Or windows onload is fired but not working as expected(that is, before windows load, onload script is fired)?

Comment: Still failure. Maybe window onload is already fired before content script load. Now I use setInterval to check document.readyState.