# Unable to append <img> into <span> in content script of Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to append an `<img>` element into a `<span>` in the content script of my chrome extension. However, it seems that the append only has an effect when I append into the `body` of the `document`, as explained in `content-script.js`. To reproduce this, click the following link and open dev tools:

http://kart.finn.no/?mapType=norge&tab=soek_i_annonser&searchKey=search_id_realestate_lettings&mapTitle=Kart+over+bolig+til+leie+&ztr=1&

Search for the `<img>` whose `id` is `seenIcon`. It will be defined when appending into the `body`, but `undefined` in all other cases.

**`manifest.json`**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "Finn.no Property Blacklist",
    "description": "Hides finn.no property search results that you've marked as \"seen\".",
    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "http://kart.finn.no/*",
        "storage"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://kart.finn.no/*"],
            "js": ["content-script.js"]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "*.png"
    ]
}
```

**`content-script.js`**

```
console.log("content script!")

function getIconSpanIfExists() {
    var spanClassName = "imagePoi";
    var matchingElements = document.getElementsByClassName(spanClassName);
    if (matchingElements.length > 1) {
        console.error(failureMessage("wasn't expecting more than one element with class name " + spanClassName));
        return null;
    }

    if (matchingElements.length === 0) {
        return null;
    }

    return matchingElements[0].parentNode;
}

function htmlReady() {
    return getIconSpanIfExists();
}

function addIcons() {
    var iconSpan = getIconSpanIfExists();

    // Append into body - works.
//    var icon = document.createElement("img");
//    icon.id = "seenIcon";
//    icon.src = chrome.extension.getURL("seen.png");
//    document.body.appendChild(icon);
//    console.log("appended " + icon.id + " into body");

    // Append into span - doesn't work, even though it says childNodes.length is 2.
    var icon = document.createElement("img");
    icon.id = "seenIcon";
    icon.src = chrome.extension.getURL("seen.png");
    icon.style.left = "200px";
    icon.style.top = "200px";
    iconSpan.appendChild(icon);
    console.log("appended " + icon.id + " into span with class imagePoi" + " new children: " + iconSpan.childNodes.length);

    // Modify innerHTML of span - doesn't work, even though innerHTML has the icon.
//    iconSpan.innerHTML += "\n<img id=\"seenIcon\""
//        + "src=\"" + chrome.extension.getURL("seen.png") + "\""
//        + "style=\"left: 200px; top: 200px;\">";
//    console.log(iconSpan.parentNode.id, iconSpan.innerHTML);
}

function init() {
    console.log("initialising content script");

    if (!htmlReady()) {
        console.log("not all HTML is loaded yet; waiting");

        var timer = setInterval(waitForHtml, 200);

        function waitForHtml() {
            console.log("waiting for required HTML elements...");
            if (htmlReady()) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                console.log("... found them!");
                addIcons();
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}

if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    console.log("document is complete")
    init();
} else {
    console.log("document is not yet ready; adding listener")
    window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
}
```

**`seen.png`**

[image: seen.png]

Why are the changes not reflected in the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The node is recreated by the site, so you need to wait a little after it's first appearance and only then add the new image.

I've tested it with a simple userscript with MutationObserver which adds the new icon each time `.imagePoi` is added to the document, including the first two appearances and subsequent on zoom-in/out.

```
setMutationHandler(document, '.imagePoi', function(observer, node) {
  node.parentNode.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    '<img src="http://www.dna-bioscience.co.uk/images/check-mark.gif">');
});

function setMutationHandler(baseNode, selector, cb) {
  var ob = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    for (var i=0, ml=mutations.length, m; (i<ml) && (m=mutations[i]); i++)
      for (var j=0, nodes=m.addedNodes, nl=nodes.length, n; (j<nl) && (n=nodes[j]); j++)
        if (n.nodeType == 1) 
          if (n = n.matches(selector) ? n : n.querySelector(selector))
            if (!cb(ob, n))
              return;
  });
  ob.observe(baseNode, {subtree:true, childList:true});
}
```

You can simplify the handler by utilizing the fact that `.imagePoi`'s mutation record's `target` has `finnPoiLayer` in its class list. But it'll be prone to breaking when site layout slightly changes.

Comment: I used `MutationObserver` originally, and ended up with several chains of functions that look very similar to the `setMutationHandler()` function above, so I switched to a simple timer as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917047/how-to-get-a-content-script-to-load-after-a-pages-javascript-has-executed/13917682#comment51201657_13917682) advice. I didn't know that you could observe nested children being added with `MutationObserver`... I see that the `subtree` argument could have been quite useful to avoid those chains. :)

Comment: I tried this out, but the `<img>` still doesn't get created for me using my original link. I added a couple of `console.log()`s in the `load` callback and before the `insertAdjacentHTML()` call, but nothing got printed. I also gave the `<img>` an `id`, but couldn't find it after the page had loaded.

Comment: Your code works with the `if (document.readyState === "complete")` check, thanks! It might be worth adding that to your answer in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: By the way, why do you disconnect it the first time? Wouldn't it be enough to leave it connected?

Comment: I disconnect it to skip doing the job the first time but apparently that's not needed.