# Chromium Extension to parse page source for keywords

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, keyword-search

I am trying to create a chromium extension that will find keywords located in the page source. They would appear as '"keywords": [these, are, keyword, examples, etc]'. I want to parse through the csv portion and have the results show up line by line in a popup or sidebar.

I've been stumbling my way through JavaScript using stackoverflow and ChatGPT. I can paste this script into the console and it will give the results I am looking for, but when I try it in my script nothing happens.

```
// contentScript.js

// Specify the keyword with a colon
const keyword = '"keywords":';

// Get the text content of the entire webpage
const pageText = document.body.innerText;

// Check if the keyword is present in the page text
const keywordIndex = pageText.indexOf(keyword);

if (keywordIndex !== -1) {
  // Find the content within brackets following the keyword
  const startIndex = pageText.indexOf('[', keywordIndex);
  const endIndex = pageText.indexOf(']', keywordIndex);

  if (startIndex !== -1 && endIndex !== -1 && startIndex < endIndex) {
    const rawResults = pageText.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex); //          Remove the leading '['
    const resultsArray = rawResults.split(',').map(value =>     value.trim().replace(/"/g, '')); // Split, trim, and remove quotations

    // Send the results to the background script
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ results: resultsArray });
  } else {
    console.log(`No results found following "${keyword}".`);
  }
} else {
  console.log(`"${keyword}" not found on the webpage.`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should check the injection of `contentScript` to your pages as injecting it before the page is fully load might result in the losing of the content for `contentScript` to scan. Instructions for injecting the script after the page loaded can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917047/how-to-get-a-content-script-to-load-after-a-pages-javascript-has-executed)

Comment: I added "run_at": "document_end" to my content_scripts but still no result. I would assume that would be all that is needed since the view-source page is static. I'm still not getting any feedback from my extension. I did try adding a timer as the commenter in that post suggested and no results there either.

Comment: Hmm, given that you pasted your script into the console and it worked, the problem might be related to the execution world of the the website and Chrome extension JavaScript. I have an accepted answer for this problem yesterday and you can check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77858366/is-it-possible-for-a-chrome-extension-using-the-modules-already-loaded-by-the-we/77858511#77858511. Hope this can help!