# How do I listen to whenever a div changes position with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to do something like this:

```
$('#myDiv').positionChanged(function() {
    alert('Yay!');
});
```

Any ideas? Is this already built into jQuery in someway?

Comment: How are the `div`s changing their position in the first place? Is there a callback function you could be using?

Comment: What do you mean by 'position'? Are we talking about `z-index`, or something like `left`? Also, possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery

Comment: simply add a call back on the function that is changing the div position

Comment: Thanks guys, I ended up using .trigger and .bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
function whereIChangePosition() {
    // Code to change position
    // ...

    $('#myDiv').trigger('positionChanged');
}
```

And my listener:

```
$('#myDiv').bind('positionChanged', function() {
    // Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately there is nothing of the kind in jquery. but that will be a good idea for maybe the next release.

So far what you can do is to add a call back yourself:

lets say you have a function that changes the position of a div.

```
function changePosition(elId,position) {
   $(elId).css('top',position);
   // or more complexe code
}
```

you can add a call back function to it.

```
function changePosition(elId,position,callback) {
   $(elId).css('top',position);

   callback();
}
```

The other method is to use **DOMAttrModified** event, but it has very low browser support as of this date