# jQuery css change event

Tags: jquery, css, events

I need to add an callback function to an css change event. Does this kind of event exists and if so, how to use it ? I tried the following but that didn't work.

```
$('#websites_table').find('tr').each(function(){
        $(this).css().change(function(){
            alert('changed');   
        });
    });
```

With friendly greetings,
Bob

Comment: No such event that I know of. Maybe you are looking at this the wrong way...perhaps you can wire up your event to whatever is going to change the css?

Comment: Are you changing CSS using jQuery, if yes make a function and call that after each change in CSS. hope this could help ...

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery

Comment: Problem is I can't do that. I use the PicNet table filter to filter the results in a table and I would rather not change the source of this plugin because of forward-compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to: [In JQuery, Is it possible to get callback function after setting new css rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974761/in-jquery-is-it-possible-to-get-callback-function-after-setting-new-css-rule)

To summarize, the css will always change before the code below runs. Ex:

```
$('#element').css('background', '#000000');
alert('This will run after the background changes.');
```