# why is this not fading in the block instead of just showing it?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, fadein

I'm trying to fade in a block using css transitions. I have a class that is set to opacity 1, after setting the display to block from none. It ignores the transition. Can anybody tell me why? Thanks.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhvC2/2/

markup:

```
<div class="fade-alert">
</div>
<button class="my_butt" type="button">click me</button>
```

css:

```
.fade-alert {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: purple;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.0s linear;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
          transition: opacity 1.0s linear;
    display: none;
}

.fade-alert.in
{
    opacity: 1;

}
```

javascript:

```
$(".my_butt").on( "click", function( e ){
$(".fade-alert").css("display", "block" );
$(".fade-alert").addClass("in"); });
```

Comment: Hm have you considered using .show() or .fadeIn() or is that not an alternative for you?

Comment: id rather have it as css, and do it this way rather than use jquery, if thats possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i used the transitionEnd event to listen to using jquery from this SO answer: [Callback when CSS3 transition finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes/9255507#9255507)

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use jQuery anyway why not just fade it in with jQuery

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/qhvC2/3/

```
$('.my_butt').click(function() {
      $('.fade-alert').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete
      });
    });
```

UPDATED

Using your code you could do it like this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/qhvC2/5/

CSS

```
.fade-alert {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: purple;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.0s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    transition: opacity 1.0s linear;
}
.in {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

JS

```
$(".my_butt").on( "click", function( e ){
    $(".fade-alert").addClass("in"); });
```

In theory with the latest option you are just adding opacity `1` and not getting involved with the `display` or `visibilty` as such

To Eradicate the height issue you could do this DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/qhvC2/6/

JS

```
$(".my_butt").on("click", function (e) {
    $(".fade-alert").addClass("in");
});
```

CSS

```
.fade-alert {
    width: 200px;
    background: purple;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.0s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    transition: opacity 1.0s linear;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.fade-alert.in {
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: i would like to do it this way with your updated version but i dont want to give the block any dimensions while being invisible, i dont want it to take up any space if its possible.

Comment: i can just move the height to the transition

Answer (score 2):

here is code you can replace this with your css and it works fine

here is fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/qhvC2/4/

```
.fade-alert {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: purple;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.0s linear;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
       -o-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
          transition: opacity 1.0s linear;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.fade-alert.in
{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: i would have liked to use it this way, but it gives the block a width and a height, and im trying to make it completely invisible without any dimensions in the markup, and take it without any space.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using transition, you could use css animation
Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zCyeD/

so you don't have to worry about having the opacity or visibility states set on the item before or after clicking. All you need to do is change it from display none to display block and when switching to display block you trigger the animation - this happens because the animation only fires once .fadeIn gets .In applied to it. The animation itself is set to last 1s and calls the keyframes. The keyframes as written instantly make the item 0% opacity and transition it to 100% opacity by the end of the animation.

jQuery:

```
$(".my_butt").on( "click", function( e ){
    $(".fade-alert").addClass("in");
});
```

CSS:

```
.fade-alert {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: purple;
    display: none;
}

.fade-alert.in
{
    display:block;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s; /* Safari 4+ */
    -moz-animation:    fadeIn 1s; /* Fx 5+ */
    -o-animation:      fadeIn 1s; /* Opera 12+ */
    animation:         fadeIn 1s; /* IE 10+ */
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

I moved your display block from a jQuery setting to just adding it to the css as you were already adding a class anyway - keeps it a bit neater.