# How to animate Positioned fixed :before selector With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

im Trying to animate positioned fixed before selector with jQuery. how can we call and animate 
:before selector in jQuery i know other method by calling class etc.. But i only want to be done it with jQuery.

html

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

css

```
#main {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background:#000;
}
#main:before {
    content:'im before';
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:blue
}
```

js

```
$("#main").hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "margin-left": "40px"
    });
    $("#main:before").animate({
        "margin-left": "40px"
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "margin-left": "0px"
    });
    $("#main:before").animate({
        "margin-left": "0px"
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pr6Cg/3/

**Note:** please give me some solution without any plugin

Comment: **jQuery to the rescue**............... *NOT*

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with javascript because you cannot select elements that don't exist.

You have to use css like so, just toggle a class

**CSS:**

```
div::before {
    content:'';
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:100px;
    background:skyblue;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    top:0;
}
div.active::before {
    top: calc( 100% - 100px );
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('div').addClass('active');
});
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JZuMX/1/)

If you can't do it this way, then i think you may have to come up with a different idea.

Comment: when i hover on :before selector its parent div animates why?

Answer (score 1):

As you You can't access pseudo-elements using JavaScript as they are generated on the fly by CSS and don't exist in the DOM. (as Suggested BY [Adrift](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783413/adrift))

try this

```
#main:before {
    content:'im before';
    position:relative;//use this 
    left:-10px;
    top:-10px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:blue
}
```

Comment: i already mentioned in my question that i m trying to animate positioned fixed element

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution but its not cross-browsers, mainly the Internet Explorer versions, it uses CSS transitions and does not require jQuery.

```
#main {
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background:#000;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left ease 0.3s;
    transition: margin-left ease 0.3s;
}

#main:before {
    content:'im before';
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:blue;
    -webkit-transition: margin-left ease 0.3s;
    transition: margin-left ease 0.3s;
}

#main:hover {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#main:hover:before {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pr6Cg/4/

Comment: i knew that but please read my question i want to be done it with jQuery

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it can be done then, if you are concern about callbacks with css transitions you can still achieve it with jQuery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes