# CSS3 transitions and javascript interaction

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way how to run some specific JavaScript code when CSS 3 transition ends?

For instance I need scale one div from 0 to 1 in y-axis and than set his content visibility from hidden to visible.

```
    <style>
    .scaleOn {-webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0); -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s; }
    </style>

    function setVisibility() {
    $("#content").css({visibility: 'visible'});
    }

    function dataHere() {
    $("#contentWrapper").addClass('scaleOn'); // and now what? I need run setVisibility when transition ends
    }

    <div style="-webkit-perspective:200px">
    <div id="contentWrapper" style="-webkit-transform: scaleY(0.0)">
    <div id="content"></div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Check also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes

Comment: As Keeper said, use [`transitionEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/transitionend)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need Javascript at all - `visibility` can be transitioned, and transitions can have delays:

```
#contentWrapper {
  visbility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, visibility 0s linear 2s;
}
.scaleOn {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

will make .scaleOn visible after 2 seconds, directly after the transform is finished.

Comment: yeah but actually i cannot be sure that the animation will be 100% done after 2 seconds