# Perform action after end of the another action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do some action after the line will fill line-holder. For example: when you click on circle1 and line runs to the and I need get alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/fresa150/8gNPA/

tried it:

```
if ($('#line').width() = 100) {
  alert('something should happen with button');
}
```

What I do wrong and how solve it?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9255507/382982) answer about CSS transition callbacks? It's a more flexible, decoupled approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to sense when css animations or transitions end, especially since `.addClass()` does not have a callback as does `.animate()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $line = $('#line'),
        tEvents = 'webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend';
    $('#circle1').click(function(){
        $line.css('width','101px').addClass('transition-slow');
    });

    $('#circle2').click(function(){
      $line.css('width','225px').addClass('transition-slow');
    });
    $('#circle3').click(function(){
      $line.css('width','350px').addClass('transition-slow');
    });
    $line.on( tEvents, function() {
        alert( 'done' );
    });  
});
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8gNPA/5/)

Reference: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end

Answer (score 2):

```
= assignment 
== means comparison without strict type checking 
=== means comparison with strict type checking
```

`a = b` always returns true in javascript so your if condition will always run

Answer (score 0):

Check for `==` - a single `=` means assignment.

Comment: Or even better, `===`

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing it right, just change the assignment "=" with comparison "==".

```
if ($('#line').width() == 100) {
  alert('something should happen with button');
}
```

Comment: `===` would be better in this circumstance

Answer (score 0):

Never is exactly 100. Do you mean greater than 100?

Also I'm guessing you want to check the line width each time the button is clicked. Therefore need to put it in each event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#circle1').click(function(){
      linewidth();
      $('#line').css('width','101px').addClass('transition-slow');
    });
    $('#circle2').click(function(){
      linewidth();
      $('#line').css('width','225px').addClass('transition-slow');
    });
    $('#circle3').click(function(){
      linewidth();
      $('#line').css('width','350px').addClass('transition-slow');
    });

    function linewidth() {
        $("#line").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){
            if ($('#line').width() > 100) {
              alert('something should happen with button');
            }
            $("#line").unbind();
        });
    }
});
```

UPDATE: Added alert delay.

Comment: I believe `linewidth()` will be called immediately the animation begins and the alert will therefore appear long before the animation is complete.

Comment: Ah. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes

Comment: Quite right. See my post above. With your permission, I can add the above reference to my post.