# How to apply 2 animation on 1 div when click on it

Tags: jquery, css, animation, magic-css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#page").click( function(){
$("#page").addClass('magictime perspectiveLeft');
$("#page").addClass('magictime perspectiveLeftRetourn');
```

What I am trying to do:

1. After clicking element("#page") this code should work:
   `$("#page").addClass('magictime perspectiveLeft');`, so the page element should go left (`perspectiveLeft`).
2. After completing this animation when I click the same element("#page") this code should work:
   `$("#page").addClass('magictime perspectiveLeftRetourn');`, so the page element should go back to its original position (`perspectiveLeftRetourn`).

The animation should be just like a greeting card opening and closing.

How do I do that?
Suggestions improving animation are appreciated.

I use https://github.com/miniMAC/magic/ for animation

Comment: Take a look here: [Callback when CSS3 transition finishes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes)

Comment: `animation-delay`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/w4sj579v/1/)

The code which i have used is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var anim = false;
    $page = $("#page");
    $page.click( function(){
        if(!anim){
            anim = true;
            if($page.hasClass('perspectiveLeft'))
                $page.removeClass('perspectiveLeft').addClass('magictime perspectiveLeftRetourn');
            else
                $page.removeClass('perspectiveLeftRetourn').addClass('magictime perspectiveLeft');
        }
    })
    $page.on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        anim = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for such a great naswer..i am nearly loose my hope.But you solve my problem.thank you very much again.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In this QA site, when an answer is realized, we do not append "(SOLVED)" to the question title. Instead, we mark a correct answer by clicking on the checkbox to the upper-left of that answer. If you come up with the answer yourself, then post your own answer, give it some time, and if no one has a better answer (your discretion), you can accept your own after a 48-hour wait period.