# React - Listening for div width change

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set a listener to determine the width of a particular div within my application. If the div is less than 800px wide, I'd like to set the style to display: none. I'm able to do it as is, but it doesn't listen to it and only removes the div if I refresh the page.

```
const [style, setStyle] = useState({});
const documentRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (documentRef.current.offsetWidth < 800) {
    const updatedStyle = {
      display: 'none',
    }
    setStyle(updatedStyle);
  }
}, [documentRef.current]);
```

Comment: Not sure, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407186/how-to-detect-html-div-width-and-height-once-div-is-done-resizing) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media query to hide something when below 800 px.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  show-lg-only {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to do it when a specific div is less than 800px, not the entire screen.

Comment: You can add the same class to specific div

Comment: Right, but that will occur when the `screen` is less than 800px width, not the div.