# Elements lose transition when given animation property

Tags: css, css-animations

This HTML element had a nice transition effect when it was clicked. However when I added another class with `animation` property, transition was lost. Look at the demo: http://codepen.io/kunokdev/pen/rewveJ

```
  <div
    class="main-menu-item zoom-in-entrance">
    Test
  </div>
```

Do `animation` and `transition` properties not stack?

```
@keyframes zoom-in-entrance
  from
    opacity: 0
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3)
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3)

  50%
    opacity: 1

.zoom-in-entrance
  -webkit-animation: zoom-in-entrance .25s forwards
  animation: zoom-in-entrance .25s forwards

.main-menu-item
  cursor: pointer
  background: $white
  transition: all .25s
  &:active
    +scale(0.95,0.95)
  i, span
    display: block
```

Animation from `animation` property only happens on page load and never again, however animation  from `transition` happens only when an element is clicked. 
How do I make them both work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your `animation` and `transition` properties are trying to affect `scale`. This is because you have specified `forwards` as the animation fill mode.

Since your animation ends on the "default" state of the item, you can use `none` instead, and the animation will not hold the `scale` at `1.0`, allowing the transition to take effect:

```
-webkit-animation: zoom-in-entrance .25s none
animation: zoom-in-entrance .25s none
```

(you can also just leave out `none` as it's the default fill mode)

Updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdgqNq

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `forwards` which persits the final state of the animation it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use js, you could remove zoom-in-entrance class after animation is finished.

[Callback when CSS3 transition finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes)