# How to wait for all animation to finish in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I have multi animations, I want to execute my code after all animations are done.

The problem with this code, that it's executed after the first animation done, and not waiting for all animations to be done.

any solution ?

```
<style>
   .userClass {
        animation: show 7s 6s forwards,zoom 8s 6s forwards,hide 5s 13s forwards;}


@@-webkit-keyframes show{
        0% {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
@@-webkit-keyframes zoom{
     //
    }
@@-webkit-keyframes hide{
     //
    }

</style>


<div class="userClass" id="user"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#user").bind("animationend", function () {           
            setTimeout(function () {
          //I want to execute code here
            }, 3000);

        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback when CSS3 transition finishes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes)

Comment: `$('.selector').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', doSomething);`

Comment: @BrettGregson this not working, it's just detecting the first animation end...tnx

Comment: To repeat the animation you can remove the CSS class for the animation using `removeClass()` and then add it again using `addClass()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "animationend" event will fire three times, first after 13 seconds, then again 1s later, then a third time 4s later (after 18s total).

Just count up a var and only handle the 3rd event.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but can't be solved with more dynamic way?.

Comment: I mean like detecting all animation ends in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to keep track of how many times `animationEnd` fires - the third time it happens, execute the code. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Keep track of how many animations have ended
  var animationEndCount = 0;

  $("#user").bind("animationend", function () {

    // Increment our counter
    animationEndCount++;

    // IF our counter is 3, run some code
    if (animationEndCount === 3) {
        setTimeout(function () {

        }, 3000);
    }
  });
});
```