# Callback on .css function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, callback

So, I am familiar with the fact that you cannot use a callback function on jQuery's `.css` function. Instead, I used the `setTimeout` function:

```
$('#header-nav').css({'left': leftBstr});

posBstr = '.level' + posB.toString();
setTimeout(function(e){
    $('#header-nav ul' + posBstr).removeClass('menu-active');
}, 300);
```

This code is meant for a mobile menu animation. There are two typed of buttons:

- go further into the menu (child categories)
- go back (parent category)

But, when using the `setTimeout` function, when I click too fast, the menu disappears, because of the removed class `menu-active`.

I already tried putting the `setTimeout` function inside a var, and use the `clearTimeout` function, but that did not work.

---

My question: is there another way to recreate the callback function on the `.css` function, without using `setTimeout`?

Comment: Maybe use `.animate`, therefore animate it using JS rather than css classes?

Comment: Hmm, I can try that. But I would also love to find a solution to a callback replacer for other situations :)

Comment: @evolutionxbox for some reason .animate gives it a delay :/

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen for binding transition end see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the `promise`

The .promise() method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have ended.

```
$('.element').css("color","yellow").promise().done(function(){
    alert( 'color is yellow!' );
});
```

Comment: You should also mention about the browser support of promises.. http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises

Comment: Works very good, but the problem is that the .css('left') animation takes 300 ms to complete. I have tried to add .delay(300) to the .removeClass(), but that did not work. Do you know a solution to that?

Comment: You can actually bind transition end in js for the element then remove it once you are done with it. But for what you are trying to do, it is much better to use `.animate`

Comment: @Huangism tried .animate, but for some reason it gave the animation a delay, and it looked not very smooth. How do I bind these transitions?

Comment: `delay` is for animations. Just to a 300ms timeout in the `done` function. That should do the trick @MaartenWolfsen

Comment: Can you try with $('#header-nav ul' + posBstr).delay(1000).removeClass('menu-active'); ?

Comment: @eisbehr Placing the setTimeout in the .done() function still results in same problem I was having in the beginning

Comment: @Loading.. .delay() does not seem to work on removeClass()

Comment: You can try to use queue for the same, if possible.
Like this way 
$("#div").addClass("error").delay(1000).queue(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("error").dequeue();
});

Comment: Try this or even 

$('.cellcontent').animate({
    left: '-=190'}, {
    easing: alert('start ani')
}, duration).promise().done(function () {
     alert('end animation');
});

Comment: Or can you create a jsfiddle to check the exact problem ?

Comment: @Loading.. it's quite hard to recreate the exact same fiddle, as I cannot share the actual code, because of my internship. I'll try to make something