# How to get jQuery to wait until an animation is finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to wait (prevent) until this animation (flip card) is finished, if you hover again while animation is running it triggers again and restart the animation. 
**1)** I want leave finish the currently animation even you hover again or you hover out. 
This is what I have tried so far:

```
if(!$(this).find(".card").is(':animated')){
    $(this).find(".card").toggleClass('flipped')
}
```

And this:

```
$(":animated").promise().done(function() {
    $(this).find(".card").toggleClass('flipped')
});
```

**2)** If you re-hover flipped card (blue part) and you leave the cursor inside dont flip it again to the red part while cursor is inside. I tried this canceling `setTimeout` with `clearTimeout` but still doesnt work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var funct = 0
    $(".container").hover(function () {
        clearTimeout(funct);
        $(this).find(".card").addClass('flipped')
    }, function () {
        var val = $(this).find(".card")
        var funct = setTimeout(function () {
            val.removeClass('flipped')
        }, 2000)
    })
 })
```

**Note:** I use setTimeOut function because I need reverse flip card 2 seconds after you hover out and I want keep it.
Here is the working snippet code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".container").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".card").toggleClass('flipped')
            
    }, function(){
        var val = $(this).find(".card")
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            val.toggleClass('flipped')
        }, 2000)
    })
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#main {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  cursor: default;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  -moz-transform-origin: right center;
  -o-transform-origin: right center;
  transform-origin: right center;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -o-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.card div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
/*
.card .front p {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
*/
.card .back p {
  margin: auto;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="main"><br>
        <section class="container">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="front"><p>Test</p></div>
                <div class="back">
                    <p>MyBack</p> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's a working answer for you. If you didn't understand, you could have asked a clarification. I am not the downvoter. I just tried justifying my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, sorry but your answer couldnt help me, I will need an answer with snippet code.

Comment: Ah... Okay... I'll make a snippet...

Comment: @SilverSurfer I have now fixed my answer with working demo.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any special tools to help you detect when a CSS animation is complete. Searching for that "Detect when a CSS animation is complete" brings up some pretty decent results.

Comment: I dont need any "special tool", just read my question and you will see it have sense.

Comment: @KevinB That was wrong moderation, I need help with my code and my specific problem not a link to other SO post..............

Comment: @SilverSurfer the question linked will help you solve your specific problem.

Comment: Review of the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes) suggests that it's an appropriate one to me.

Comment: I agree that it is an appropriate dupe closure; discussion about reopening this also took place in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40028710#40028710) chatroom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Run a conditional check first** to determine *if* the trigger class `flipped` has already been added to the element in question.
This will imply that the animation is still running or currently active (if the class `flipped` is already present).

```
if (!$(this).find(".card").hasClass('flipped')) {
      $(this).find(".card").toggleClass('flipped')
    }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container").hover(function() {
    if (!$(this).find(".card").hasClass('flipped')) {
      $(this).find(".card").toggleClass('flipped')
    }

  }, function() {
    var val = $(this).find(".card")
    setTimeout(function() {
      val.removeClass('flipped')
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#main {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  cursor: default;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  -moz-transform-origin: right center;
  -o-transform-origin: right center;
  transform-origin: right center;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -o-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.card div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/*
.card .front p {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
*/

.card .back p {
  margin: auto;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="main"><br>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <p>MyBack</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then replace the `.toggleClass()` method with the `.removeClass()` method in your `setTimeout()` function for better "fool-proofing" and more reliable application during intended events - so that this class is never unintentionally added when it should simply be removed.

#### Edit

To address the issue you've pointed out in the comments, see what the embedded code snippet below demonstrates.
Essentially, a *class is added as a flag to check against* during specific events at specific times.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.container').hover(function() {
    if (!$(this).find('.card').hasClass('flipped')) {
      $(this).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped')
    }
    $(this).find('.card').addClass('hovered'); /* add class - this will be our flag we'll check against */

  }, function() {
    var val = $(this).find('.card');
    $(this).find('.card').removeClass('hovered'); /* remove class - if we refrain from hovering over again, the condition block below will return true and run the code within */
    setTimeout(function() {
      if(!val.hasClass('hovered')) {
        val.removeClass('flipped')
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
  
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#main {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  width: 30%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  cursor: default;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
  -moz-transform-origin: right center;
  -o-transform-origin: right center;
  transform-origin: right center;
}

.card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  -o-transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
  transform: translateX( -100%) rotateY( -180deg);
}

.card div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .front {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/*
.card .front p {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
*/

.card .back p {
  margin: auto;
}

.card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  transform: rotateY( 180deg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="main"><br>
    <section class="container">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="front">
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back">
          <p>MyBack</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks its a nice idea,  makes me sense :) . But still have a problem, if you re-hover blue part and leave the cursor inside, the flipped card goes to red part, and I dont want that happens.

Comment: Answer updated to address that issue (collapsed code snippet).

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thanks for your answer and your help.

Comment: Dude help vamped and then fell straight off his rocker ^. Flagging whole discussion as non-constructive haha

Comment: @SilverSurfer well this helped me as much as it helped you. Looks like I missed quite the party here though. And I do think the rep reversal script might have its work cut out for it come 03:00 UTC