# jQuery - animationComplete duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

My project uses the `animationComplete` function provided within the jQuery mobile library - https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js

Since a sequence of object is animation along with a bunch of execution to be done on each animation point, the `animationComplete` function serves as a good callback to execute the required functions.

However, the duration of the animationComplete callback seems to be delayed given that duration is increased by 3 times on purpose within the library).

```
// Parse the duration since it's in second multiple by 1000 for milliseconds
// Multiply by 3 to make sure we give the animation plenty of time.
duration = parseFloat(
    $( this ).css( props[ animationType ].duration )
 ) * 3000;
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same objective (perhaps without using the library)?

Comment: you could use jquery animate as well.

Comment: Hi Daniel, the transition is done in css and I am unable to change it. Is there a better way to listen to it with javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback when CSS3 transition finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255279/callback-when-css3-transition-finishes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use eventlistener `animationend` to check the end of a css animation.

```js
const myBtn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
const myH1 = document.getElementById('myh1');

const removeClass = (e) => {
  console.log('animation ends');
  e.target.classList.remove('animated', 'bounce');
}

const animate = () => {
  myH1.classList.add('animated', 'bounce');

  myH1.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", removeClass);
  myH1.addEventListener("mozAnimationEnd", removeClass);
  myH1.addEventListener("MSAnimationEnd", removeClass);
  myH1.addEventListener("oanimationend", removeClass);
  myH1.addEventListener("animationend", removeClass);
}

myBtn.addEventListener('click', animate);
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  from,
  20%,
  53%,
  80%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  43% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from,
  20%,
  53%,
  80%,
  to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  43% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -30px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -15px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -4px, 0);
  }
}

.bounce {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
  animation-name: bounce;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="myh1">Animate me</h1>
<button>click to animate</button>
```