# how to learn and change javascript transform scale

Tags: javascript, if-statement, transform

```
$('#scroller').css('transform');
```

This div is a default value.

```
Transform scale(1)
```

i want to change value. if `#scroller transform scale(3)` give me `alert`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#scroller').css('transform', 'scale(3)');
alert('Changed');`

The css change will always execute before the alert. 
See also [In JQuery, Is it possible to get callback function after setting new css rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974761/in-jquery-is-it-possible-to-get-callback-function-after-setting-new-css-rule)

Comment: Additionally `$('#scroller').css('transform', 'scale(3)')` will be 'truthy' even when there is no div on the page called #scroller, so if you had an if statement it will always run.