# Executing one jquery statement after css change is complete

Tags: jquery

I would like to have jquery execute certain statements only AFTER it has completed applying my css change. However, despite trying to search for the answer... I have been unable to so far. Any pointers, would be appreciated.

```
$('#elements').css( 'visibility', 'hidden'); 
$('#another_element').slideDown(); // should only be executed after the above is completely done
```

Comment: It would be happened like that..

Comment: That's what I expected. However, both statements appear to begin executing at the same time. I would like to ensure that the second statement does not execute at all, until the first is completed... even if it takes some time.

Comment: $('#elements').css( 'visibility', 'hidden');  would be instant un-less you have some css transition/animation

Comment: Again, that's what I thought. However, due to other reasons if the first statement is not instantaneous.. the second is still executed. I don't want it to begin until the first is complete !

Comment: @Grateful It would be great if you provide a demo on what you are talking about rather making an unproductive discussion.

Comment: @Grateful Other solution is to add a timer which checks for the css and then execute the subsequent command. Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24484924/2000051

Comment: Can you add the code to a fiddle? jquery's .css has no call back and should be doing what you want.

Comment: Not tested, but you could try jquery's hide() instead of the css call, with a duration of 0 and do the slidedown in the complete callback

Comment: @Me.Name I wasn't looking for a way to "display: none" the element. I was specifically asking for a way to "visibility: hidden".

Comment: Oh right, sorry, not the same thing of course. Don't know if it's acceptable to use transparancy (opacity 0) instead of hidden, otherwise you could try fadeOut to 0 with duration 0 with a callback. `$('#elements').fadeTo(0,0, function(){
  //slidedown
});`   The only other option I know of is webit transition listereners, but don't know if you can tweak those to the specific event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So the answer is that since there is no callback for the css function, it's not possible.