# jQuery.css() - marginLeft vs. margin-left?

Tags: jquery, css, margin

With jQuery.css() I've been told I can use the following two functions for the same results:

```
$(".element").css("marginLeft") = "200px";

$(".element").css("margin-left") = "200px";
```

I've always used `marginLeft` as this is what is used in the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/css/

> Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not
>   supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin,
>   use: $(elem).css('marginTop') and $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so
>   on.

Why has jQuery allowed for `marginLeft` as well as `margin-left`? It seems pointless and uses more resources to be converted to the CSS `margin-left`?

Comment: As an aside [`.css`](http://jsperf.com/cowbell-css-styles/2) is slow as hell compared to classes. Basically `.style` and `.css` are the devil.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

jQuery's underlying code passes these strings to the DOM, which allows you to specify the CSS property name or the DOM property name in a very similar way:

```
element.style.marginLeft = "10px";
```

is equivalent to:

```
element.style["margin-left"] = "10px";
```

> Why has jQuery allowed for marginLeft as well as margin-left? It seems pointless and uses more resources to be converted to the CSS margin-left?

jQuery's not really doing anything special.  It may alter or proxy some strings that you pass to `.css()`, but in reality there was *no work* put in from the jQuery team to allow either string to be passed.  There's no extra resources used because the DOM does the work.

Answer (score 40):

I think it is so it can keep consistency with the available options used when settings multiple css styles in one function call through the use of an object, for example...

```
$(".element").css( { marginLeft : "200px", marginRight : "200px" } );
```

as you can see the property are not specified as strings. JQuery also supports using string if you still wanted to use the dash, or for properties that perhaps cannot be set without the dash, so the following still works...

```
$(".element").css( { "margin-left" : "200px", "margin-right" : "200px" } );
```

without the quotes here, the javascript would not parse correctly as property names cannot have a dash in them.

EDIT: It would appear that JQuery is not actually making the distinction itsleft, instead it is just passing the property specified for the DOM to care about, most likely with `style[propertyName];`

Comment: "engine doesn't need to convert the string." lol what? I think you need to learn how properties work.

Comment: a property is merely a valid identifier, `marginLeft: value` and `"marginLeft": value` are the same thing.

Comment: @Raynos, yes but as some point along the way something has to parse 1 of them (or maybe both) to identify what it is actually wanting to do. Now, from reading the other answer I concede that JQuery is possible using a string version of both when calling the DOM style[] property anyway so in this case there would be no difference as the DOM would still be working with a string either way (or maybe JQuery passes them differently - I cannot find any resources to prove either way)

Comment: Sorry, at which point would it _not_ be working with a string?

Comment: In my first example marginLeft is not a string, in the second "margin-left" is a string. Maybe this is the way javascript handles define objects, but surely it has to parse the "margin-left" string to create a property from it? Or am I wrong?

Comment: no, again that's not how properties on an object work, they are both strings. `marginLeft: "200px"` is just sugar for `"marginLeft": "200px"`. And the parsing is done when it loads the file, not at run-time. Arguably it's ever so marginally slower (couple of nano seconds?) but that's an epic micro optimisation.

Comment: @musefan Have you considdered that your code is 95% slower than Andy E's? [Proven fact](http://jsperf.com/cowbell-css-styles).

Comment: @Raynos: OK, so now we get somewhere. I didnt realise that the parsing is done at runtime. Thanks for the info ;)

Comment: @musefan Yeah, I'm using a browser with a faster javaScript engine than you are. Check out the results pane for ie6-9,ff4, and chrome. Point is, jQuery slows down the web needlessly because it runs a bunch of string manipulation and lookup tables... and all you needed was two lines of code.

Comment: @Incognito: Looks like I should switch back down to stable Chrome

Comment: @musefan If you'd like to. Opera generally kills all the other guys at DOM and other features like parseInt, give it a whirl if you're looking for the fastest right now.

Comment: $(".element").css({"margin-left":"240px"}); is worked for me(removing the extra spaces ).Thank you @musefan.

Answer (score 10):

Late to answer, but no-one has specified that css property with dash won't work in object declaration in jquery:

```
.css({margin-left:'200px'});//won't work
.css({marginLeft:'200px'});//works
```

So, do not forget to use quotes if you prefer to use dash style property in jquery code.

```
.css({'margin-left':'200px'});//works
```

Answer (score 6):

when is **marginLeft** being used:

```
$("div").css({
    marginLeft:'12px',
    backgroundPosition:'10px -10px',
    minHeight: '40px'
});
```

As you can see, attributes that has a hyphen on it are converted to camelcased format. Using the `margin-left` from the previous code block above would make JavaScript bonkers because it will treat the hyphen as an operation for subtraction.

when is **margin-left** used:

```
$("div").css("margin-left","12px").css("background-position","10px -10px").css("min-height","40px");
```

Theoretically, both code blocks will do the same thing. We can allow hyphens on the second block because it is a string value while compared to the first block, it is somewhat an object.

Now that should make sense.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is simply supporting the way CSS is written.

Also, it ensures that no matter how a browser returns a value, it will be understood

> jQuery can equally interpret the CSS and DOM formatting of
>   multiple-word properties. For example, jQuery understands and returns
>   the correct value for both .css('background-color') and
>   .css('backgroundColor').

Comment: jQuery's taking credit for something it didn't do here, the underlying DOM handles the two different strings.

Answer (score -1):

Hi i tried this it is working.

```
$("#change_align").css({"margin-top":"-39px","margin-right":"0px","margin-bottom":"0px","margin-left":"719px"});
```