# How to detect margin-left of element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, margin

Wird, I thought this is obvious but not necessarily, can anybody tell me how to detect margin with jQuery? I have this and in console i have good result but it's not working on page:

```
var margin_left = circle.css('margin-left').toLowerCase();
circles_container.css('margin-left', -margin_left + 'px');
```

Much thx for help.

Comment: What you'r doing on page? Post entire code... who is "circle"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902324/jquery-css-marginleft-vs-margin-left

Comment: `var margin_left = parseInt(circle.css('margin-left'));` ?

Comment: I searched but could not find, thx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this should be more accurate:

```
var margin_left = circle.css('margin-left');
circles_container.css({marginLeft: '-'+margin_left});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK i have this and also it's work:

```
var margin_left = l_circle.css('margin-left').replace("px", "");
container.css('margin-left', -margin_left + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var marginLeftVal = circle.css('marginLeft');
marginLeftVal = parseInt(marginLeftVal)*-1;
circles_container.css({
            marginLeft: marginLeftVal 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

YOu could also start using the JSizes library.

Found on this page:
http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jsizes/

Allows you to easily retrieve or set a property of margin, padding, or other attributes.