# ZIndex vs z-index css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index

Is there any Difference between the following properties

```
$("element").css("zIndex")
```

and

```
$("element").css("z-index")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902324/jquery-css-marginleft-vs-margin-left

Comment: Thank You for sharing the Link,I will read further