# How to detect CSS3 resize events

Tags: javascript, css, resize, dom-events

The CSS3 resize property can be assigned to arbitrary elements. I'm looking for a way to detect such a resize on, say, divs (I don't mind it only working in Firefox at the moment):

```
div {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Unfortunately, the `onresize` event seems not to be fired on the div. How can I detect in JavaScript when such a user-instantiated resize has happened?

*Edit:* FWIW I had opened a bug report over at Mozilla. If you want to track it: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701648

Comment: @DaveL nope, that only works for the `window` object.

Comment: from what i know, the `onresize` event only works with `window`. Does the click event fire when you resize? Maybe you could use that ( to recalculate width/height when clicked)

Comment: I could detect mousemove over the div but was hoping for a more comfortable solution.

Comment: For me overflow:hidden on body turned off resize event on FF and Chrome. Same issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Listen to [`DOMAttrModified` events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents).  Got the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery/1397500#1397500), [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/r2NFT/) appears to work in Firefox 8 (if you open the console).

Comment: Cool, that's in any case way better than mouseover catching. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't fire in Chrome, Linux

Comment: @Alp I believe DOM2 Mutation Events have been [replaced by DOM4 Mutation Observers](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142648) in recent builds.  [Try this article](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers).

Comment: @robertc I dont think they work with resize https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=293948

Comment: Thanks @robertc! The mentioned issue is now fixed and MutationObserver worked for me. I've added it as an answer.

Comment: @Boldewyn, somewhere between robertc's nice answer/comment and today, many years later, this has been deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events Care to accept one of the other answers for future readers?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/pckrf/ shows that today, years later, Firefox still supports this, but Chrome and Safari do not.

Comment: When you're handling `document.body` events for elements with `resize` CSS property, beware of this Chrome-specific edge case: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1456570

Answer (score 31):

Resizing is like a style change. As such it can be observed with a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). The more specific [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) is probably even better:

```js
let observer = new ResizeObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log('mutations:', mutations);
});

let child = document.querySelector('textarea');
observer.observe(child);
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Indeed. Good idea!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Safari 10, even with `WebKitMutationObserver`.

Comment: Looks like this answer is outdated too, and you should be using [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) today instead.

Comment: Thanks! The snippet with `MutationObserver` still works for me in Chrome 95. But `ResizeObserver` works too. I've updated the answer. Do you see any indication that `MutationObserver` will stop working in the future? I don't remember where I used it...

Comment: Note that `attributes: true` is not relevant to `ResizeObserver()`. [Specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/resize-observer/#enumdef-resizeobserverboxoptions)

Answer (score 7):

Since the `resize` event clearly doesn't work (currently, at least), you can try one of these alternative options:

1. Use a combination of `mousedown`, `mousemove` and/or `mouseup` to tell whether the `div` is being / has been resized. If you want really fine-grained control you can check in every `mousemove` event how much / if the div has been resized. If you don't need that, you can simply not use `mousemove` at all and just measure the `div` in `mousedown` and `mouseup` and figure out if it was resized in the latter.
2. Poll every 200ms or so (depending on your needs) and compare the current size with the last known size. See [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Comment: Yes, polling and mousemove are valid options, thanks. I thought of them myself. +1 for them. robertc's answer seems more elegant, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ResizeSensor` class of the css-element-queries polyfill from

https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries

It allows you to call a javascript function on size changes for all types of elements, not only for `window`. It sets up a real sensor, not a javascript `setTimeout` poll.

Use it like this:

```
new ResizeSensor($('#myelement'), function() {
    console.log("myelement's size has changed");
});
```

Supported browsers are: all incl. IE6+.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work pretty well for me:

```
$("body").on('mousedown mousemove', ".resizeItem", function () {
    console.log($(this).height());
})
```

> "Use a combination of mousedown, mousemove and/or mouseup"

as per Felixs answer.

Especially useful when combining a custom search result panel with Dev Extremes Scroll View and you want full control over it.

```
$("body").on('mousedown mousemove', ".scrollContainer", function () {
    var h = $(this).height() - 20;
    $(".scrollArea").dxScrollView('instance').option('height', h);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

According to [this site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it only works in internet explorer 9.

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/3Zva3/

Comment: I thought so, that onresize should fire in this case. I go looking, if there's a bug report over at bugzilla.

Comment: That MSDN page is for the `window.resize` event - which fires when you resize the browser window, not an element resize event, when you resize a tag with a css3 resize property through dragging a handle.