# -moz-resize event

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have an element that is using `-moz-resize` CSS style. This style enables resizing of an element with the mouse.

Are there any events that fire when I am resizing an element?

Comment: You could probably use [DOMAttrModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Mutation_events) to listen to the change in `height`/`width`. It might have a performance impact though.

Comment: Why `-moz-resize` rather than `resize`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/resize doesn't even mention the prefixed form and at least Firefox 12 doesn't support it.

Comment: Cant use resize. -moz-resize is the way how resizing is implemented in Sitecore (in Firefox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.onresize

> Only the window object has an onresize event.

Idea: You could give the item some onClick / onmouseup event, which stores and checks local element width / height. So you could trigger / fire some other events / functions

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Comment: I cringe every time I see a link to w3schools. Are you aware of [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: @zzzzBov yup I know w3fools :) I just wanted to show the dom attributes for object events! ;)

Comment: "Only the window object has an onresize event" - there is a way to do resize detection in an event-based way for any DOM element. I posted my answer here, but a mod deleted it :(

Answer (score 0):

I recently posted an answer on a question that called for the same solution:

> [Detect if an element has been resized via javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255162/detect-if-an-element-has-been-resized-via-javascript)

To use the method below for your case, just pass in the element you want to listen for resizes events on and the function you want to call when it happens. It doesn't matter whether or not the element has the CSS resize property on it, this works for any DOM element. One caveat: the element must be able to contain children, else you need to wrap the element in question - like an input or img - and set the listener on that.

WARNING: This is a lot of content for one SO answer, you can read the full post on my blog: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/

---

## HTML

The following HTML block is auto-appended to any element you attach a resize event to. You can only attach resize events to elements that allow children – basically, no elements declared with self-closing tags.

```
<div class="resize-sensor">
    <div class="resize-overflow"><div></div></div>
    <div class="resize-underflow"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.resize-sensor, .resize-sensor > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

## JavaScript Code/Methods

The following is the JavaScript you’ll need to enable resize event listening. The first two functions are prerequisites that are used in the main addResizeListener and removeResizeListener methods. (further details on the addFlowListener method are available in the overflow/underflow event post, as previous mentioned)

```
function addFlowListener(element, type, fn){
    var flow = type == 'over';
    element.addEventListener('OverflowEvent' in window ? 'overflowchanged' : type + 'flow', function(e){
        if (e.type == (type + 'flow') ||
        ((e.orient == 0 && e.horizontalOverflow == flow) ||
        (e.orient == 1 && e.verticalOverflow == flow) ||
        (e.orient == 2 && e.horizontalOverflow == flow && e.verticalOverflow == flow))) {
            e.flow = type;
            return fn.call(this, e);
        }
    }, false);
};

function fireEvent(element, type, data, options){
    var options = options || {},
        event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent(type, 'bubbles' in options ? options.bubbles : true, 'cancelable' in options ? options.cancelable : true);
    for (var z in data) event[z] = data[z];
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
};

function addResizeListener(element, fn){
    var resize = 'onresize' in element;
    if (!resize && !element._resizeSensor) {
        var sensor = element._resizeSensor = document.createElement('div');
            sensor.className = 'resize-sensor';
            sensor.innerHTML = '<div class="resize-overflow"><div></div></div><div class="resize-underflow"><div></div></div>';

        var x = 0, y = 0,
            first = sensor.firstElementChild.firstChild,
            last = sensor.lastElementChild.firstChild,
            matchFlow = function(event){
                var change = false,
                width = element.offsetWidth;
                if (x != width) {
                    first.style.width = width - 1 + 'px';      
                    last.style.width = width + 1 + 'px';
                    change = true;
                    x = width;
                }
                var height = element.offsetHeight;
                if (y != height) {
                    first.style.height = height - 1 + 'px';
                    last.style.height = height + 1 + 'px';      
                    change = true;
                    y = height;
                }
                if (change && event.currentTarget != element) fireEvent(element, 'resize');
            };

        if (getComputedStyle(element).position == 'static'){
            element.style.position = 'relative';
            element._resizeSensor._resetPosition = true;
        }
        addFlowListener(sensor, 'over', matchFlow);
        addFlowListener(sensor, 'under', matchFlow);
        addFlowListener(sensor.firstElementChild, 'over', matchFlow);
        addFlowListener(sensor.lastElementChild, 'under', matchFlow);  
        element.appendChild(sensor);
        matchFlow({});
    }
        var events = element._flowEvents || (element._flowEvents = []);
        if (events.indexOf(fn) == -1) events.push(fn);
        if (!resize) element.addEventListener('resize', fn, false);
        element.onresize = function(e){
            events.forEach(function(fn){
                fn.call(element, e);
            });
        };
};

function removeResizeListener(element, fn){
    var index = element._flowEvents.indexOf(fn);
    if (index > -1) element._flowEvents.splice(index, 1);
    if (!element._flowEvents.length) {
        var sensor = element._resizeSensor;
        if (sensor) {
            element.removeChild(sensor);
            if (sensor._resetPosition) element.style.position = 'static';
            delete element._resizeSensor;
        }
        if ('onresize' in element) element.onresize = null;
        delete element._flowEvents;
    }
    element.removeEventListener('resize', fn);
};
```

## Usage

Here’s a pseudo code usage of this solution:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('my_element'),
    myResizeFn = function(){
        /* do something on resize */
    };
addResizeListener(myElement, myResizeFn);
removeResizeListener(myElement, myResizeFn);
```

Comment: As I stated on the other question I used this answer on - it is not the same question, but this answer serves both, duping seems wrong in that situation, correct?