# On element's width change using css event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, events

I am setting different `width` for an element according to the screen size (using `@media`). I wanna know if the width change triggers an event or not. I tried

```
$('.itable').bind('resize', function() {
    console.log("resize")
});
```

but no luck. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You probably want to use resize() with window.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255162/detect-if-an-element-has-been-resized-via-javascript