# How to dynamically change classes when DIV width changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I know how to change classes with Jquery when the window size is changed, but I need it to be based on the width of a DIV and change dynamically when the DIV's width changes.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

   var wrapWidth = $('.info-wrap').width();

    if (wrapWidth >= 500) {

      $('#partOne').addClass('big');
      $('#partTwo').addClass('big');

    } else {

      $('#partOne').removeClass('big');
      $('#partTwo').removeClass('big');
    }
});
```

This works when the window size changes. But, what can I use insead of $(window).resize to get the width of the DIV as it changes?

Comment: What triggers the resizing of the `div`?

Comment: If DIV's width changes only on window resize, what is the issue here?

Comment: What's calling the resize? An existing plugin? or does it have CSS3 `resize:both` enabled? If it is bound by CSS3, check here -> [How to detect CSS3 resize events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082729/how-to-detect-css3-resize-events)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed

Comment: Could not help myself: you can rewrite this as $('#partOne, #partTwo').toggleClass('big', wrapWidth >= 500)

Comment: On newer browsers use `MutationObserver` on older you will need to look at `Mutation Events`

Comment: It also depends on how the width is set `width="100px"`, `style="width: 100px;"`, or by `class="widthClass1"` on the element (or possibly some other).

Comment: There is another DIV on the page that changes width based on another event and thus changes the width of this DIV. So using (window) will not work because the window size doesn't change in this case.

Comment: See: [Can you have a javascript hook trigger after a DOM element's style object changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868104/can-you-have-a-javascript-hook-trigger-after-a-dom-elements-style-object-change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to use a plugin for JQuery, such [Ben Alman's plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/).

I don't think there exists something that detects when a div gets resize, only the window.

Comment: Note: This plugin uses polling.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of observing the elements attributes.

See: [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and [`Mutation Events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events)

CSS

```
#watch {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<div id="watch" style="width: 100px; height: 50px;"></div>
```

Javascript

```
/*jslint sub: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */
/* global global */

(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    if (typeof global.MutationObserver !== "function") {
        global.MutationObserver = global.WebKitMutationObserver || global.MozMutationObserver;
    }

    var watch = document.getElementById("watch");

    function whenClicked() {
        watch.style.width = "200px";
    }

    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", whenClicked, false);

    if (typeof global.MutationObserver !== "function") {
        // chrome doesn't despatch an event for "DOMAttrModified"
        watch.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", function (evt) {
            console.log("Attribute changed", evt.target);
        }, false);
    } else {
        var observer = new global.MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
                    console.log("Attribute changed", mutation);
                }
            });
        });

        observer.observe(watch, {
            attributes: true,
            childList: true,
            characterData: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    }
}(window));
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/PN7W3/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a plugin sometime back for **[attrchange](http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/)** listener which basically adds a listener function on attribute change. This seems to come in handy for scenario that you had mentioned where you need a handler to check the width and height.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CKTk3/1/

```
    var prevWidth = $('#test').width(),
        prevHeight = $('#test').height();

    $('#test').attrchange({
        callback: function (e) {
            var curWidth = $(this).width(),
                curHeight = $(this).height();            
            if (prevWidth !== curWidth ||
                prevHeight !== curHeight) {
                console.log('resized: width - ' + prevWidth + ' : ' + curWidth + ' height - ' + prevHeight + ' : ' + curHeight);

                prevWidth = curWidth;
                prevHeight = curHeight;
            }            
        }
    }).resizable();
```

**Plugin page:** http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/

Comment: +1, like the tracking fix for MutationObserver. Much better than the polling solution.

Comment: @Xotic750 Thanks for checking out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get div width by div class or id. ex: $("#div-id").width();