# "DOMAttrModified" event not supported by modern browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, web

Here are the codes ([Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rzf21j7t/)) :

```
<a href="#">Click me!</a>

<script>
var a = document.body.children[0]

a.onclick = function() {
  alert('in onlick')
  this.setAttribute('href', 'lala')
  alert('out onclick')
  return false
}

function onpropchange() {
  alert('onpropchange')
}

if (a.addEventListener) { // FF, Opera
  a.addEventListener('DOMAttrModified', onpropchange, false)
}
if (a.attachEvent) { // IE 
  a.attachEvent('onpropertychange', onpropchange)
} 
</script>
```

When the `<a href>Click me!</a>` is clicked. The `alert('onpropchange')` is not executed.. (I'm using Chrome 43.0) Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: Use the modern [```MutationObserver```](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) An example can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709726/how-to-dynamically-change-classes-when-div-width-changes/17710809#17710809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs of mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)

> This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.

Use [mutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead if possible.