# How to handle the beginning of resize in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

I'm trying to call a function right at the start of dragging but I can't, this div can't handle click or mousedown events on the resize icon area so I'm forced to handle it on mouseover event.

http://jsfiddle.net/PLBT6/

HTML

```
<div>hey</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
    width:30%;
    border:4px solid green;
    resize:horizontal;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Javascript

```
$("div").on("mousemove.resizer",function(e) {
    var draggingstarted = false;
    var bottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    var right = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();

    if (e.pageY<bottom-3 && e.pageY>bottom-16
        && e.pageX<right-3 && e.pageX>right-16){
        if (draggingstarted){
            console.log("started dragging");
        } else if (e.which==1) draggingstarted=true; //left click
        //else if (e.which==0) draggingstarted=false; //no clicks
        console.log(e.which, draggingstarted);
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570390/resize-event-for-textarea

Comment: @megawac I can handle resize but I cant handle the beginning of the resize event.

Comment: migth help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082729/how-to-detect-css3-resize-events

Comment: Sure, if you want to use a resizer you're gonna probably need a plugin

Comment: using plugin will be best approach for cross browser compatability

Comment: I only need it to work for Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I made it:

http://jsfiddle.net/PLBT6/1/

```
var ready = false; //entered with no clicks
$("div").on("mousemove",function(e) {
    var bottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
    var right = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();

    if (e.pageY<bottom-3 && e.pageY>bottom-16 && e.pageX<right-3 && e.pageX>right-16){
        if (e.which==1 && ready) {console.log("drag started");ready=false;} //left click
        else if (e.which==0) {console.log("ready");ready=true;} //no clicks
    } else ready=false;
});
$("div").on("mouseout",function(e) {
    ready=false;
});
```