# How to call a function on div resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

There is a new CSS property, called resize, so the divs are resizeable too. But how to attach an event listener? Because `.onresize` works only on the window object

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3y0gfj8j/

---

Edit:

I don't want to use JQuery. It's not a duplicate question.
I've found only JQuery solutions for this problem, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082729/how-to-detect-css3-resize-events

Comment: I don't want to use JQuery. It's not a duplicate

Comment: look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082729/how-to-detect-css3-resize-events

Comment: DOMAttrModified doesn't works in chrome

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect DIV's dimension changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492683/how-to-detect-divs-dimension-changed)

Comment: I've found only JQuery solutions for this problem, that's why I asked this question. Stop posting possible duplicates please

Comment: @IterAtor You're right, I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: mutation observer? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 2):

I worked around it this way.  Seems to work OK in Firefox at least.
It fires when you take your cursor off the resize 'grabber' on the bottom right of the element you're resizing.

```
<DOCTYPE=html>
<html>

<script>
function functionname()
{
//replace this line with the script you want executed
}
</script>

<style>
#idname {resize:both;}
</style>

<body>
<div id="idname" onmouseout="functionname();"></div>
</body>

</html>
```