# Detect When User Resizes Div With CSS resize: both

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know I can use `ResizeObserver` to detect when a div's size changes, but I would like to only know when the user resizes the div with the CSS property `resize: both`, and not when the page gets resized.

```js
// Detect when user resizes element with the property resize: both;
```

```css
div {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hi!
</div>
```

Comment: Will this question help you? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082729/how-to-detect-css3-resize-events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MutationObserver` for this. [Source here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807059/4781067).

```js
let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log('Resized');
});

let child = document.querySelector('div');
observer.observe(child, { attributes: true });
```

```css
div {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hi!
</div>
```

Comment: This seems great especially from the perspective of browser compatibility. [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#browser_compatibility) vs [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver#browser_compatibility). And it only detects resize with mouse.

Comment: I have found a small problem. If `div` width is `%` or `vw`, the units seems stops working after resizing `div`, which means the width is fixed.

Comment: Thanks so much, only triggers with events from cursor. Works great!

Comment: This also triggers if the dimensions have changed programmatically, not by the user. If you only want to listen for user changes, you can have a boolean variable that is set to `true` on `mousedown` and `false` on `mouseup`, and react to mutations only when the flag is `true`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ResizeObserver`:

```js
const observer = new ResizeObserver(mutations => {
  console.clear()
  console.log(mutations[0].contentRect.width, mutations[0].contentRect.height)
});

observer.observe(test);
```

```css
#test {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='test'>Hi!</div>
```

Comment: This answer seems good too. It's much better than mine :)

Comment: already did this, I was looking for a way to **only** detect when divs resized have been resized with the css property `resize: both`.  **This does not answer the question.**

Comment: I have deleted my answer because I've found a serious bug in it. I used mousedown/mouseup event. I think they may also be useful in your code.