# How to determin that javascript has finished doing something

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

JS on ios is rather slow. For example in this piece of code, the Js adds the class before being able to add the block style. This breaks an animation i have on the page.

```
comments.style.display="block";comments.className = "show";
```

I have a workaround that fixes the issue on ios but just feels wrong:

```
comments.style.display="block";setTimeout(function(){comments.className = "show";},1)
```

Is there any way to determine if the block style has been set and only then trigger the second part?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: just use a simple if/then statement to check (?)

Comment: @harmonickey didn't even know "then" existed! need to look into that :)

Comment: haha, yeah.  Just a clarification of what I would have meant by "if" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use an if?

```
<div id="foo" style="display: none;">foo</div>

var div = document.getElementById( "foo"  );
if ( div.style.display == "none" ) {
    div.style.display = "block";
}
```

If you want to listen to a class change (or a style change) "event", you can try these links:

- [Event detect when css property changed using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery) <= this solves the problem without jQuery
- [jQuery - Fire event if CSS class changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed)
- [Trigger event using Jquery on CSS change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671001/trigger-event-using-jquery-on-css-change)
- [Is it possible to listen to a "style change" event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157963/is-it-possible-to-listen-to-a-style-change-event)

I think the first one will solve your problem. Here is the code:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener( "DOMAttrModified", function( evt ){
    if ( evt.attrName === "style" ) {
        if ( evt.newValue.indexOf( "block" ) != -1 ) {
            alert( "do something!" );
        }
    }
}, false );

document.getElementById( "foo" ).style.display = "block";
```

Comment: I sincerely do not see how I can write it down any clearer. I want it to set a class. When that is done trigger something else. My code above just runs all of it without waiting for each step to finish.

Comment: So, you want to listen to a "change class" event?

Comment: The links you provided are only for jquery :(. doesn't help.

Comment: No, the first one don't use jQuery. I writing an example... Wait a moment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a glorious mess of a hack that may work:

```
comments.blockStyleEvent = function() {
   if ( this.style.display === "block" ) {
      this.onBlockStyleEvent.apply(this);
   }
};

comments.onBlockStyleEvent = function() {
   this.className = "show";
};

setInterval(function(){
  comments.blockStyleEvent();
}, 1);
```

You could also create two css classes one `show` and another `showAsBlock` for example then you could do this:

```
// somewhere else
comments.className = "hide";

// ...then
comments.className = "showAsBlock";
```

Comment: your second answer (2 classes) may indeed fix this! great, easy & obvious solution :). 'll try and report back!

Comment: No problem, simpler is better, much, much, much better.  Also a CSS preproccessor (e.g. SASS or LESS) could help reduce some repetitiveness if that becomes a problem.