# How can I make my jquery if/then statement update live?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a simple conditional that says if div1 is displayed, then change div2's display to none.  However, I want this to be updated live.  So anytime div1 display is 'grid', div2 disappears from sight.

```
<script>
    if($('.div1').css("display") == "grid") {
        $('div2').css({"display":"none"});
        }
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The key idea here is to use _events_ that fire whenever something happens.

Comment: This question might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671001/trigger-event-using-jquery-on-css-change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A block of javascript code will not just magically run whenever convenient for you, unless you make it so that it is run in such a way. What you have written will just run once, and move on. Javascript will not by itself will look for when things change.

You need to track the change and run your code after that change. If you are writing the javascript for a site, you probably know when these changes occur, so you can execute your code block when they do occur. For example if `div1` changes to `grid` when user `click`s a button, then you can bind your function to its `click event` so handle the situation.

A more advanced method would be to  watch for changes on DOM and run a function when they occur. You can do this with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)s. You can do precisely what you want, `if div changes to grid, run myFunction()` for example.

Another method would be to have a function run on intervals but this is an obsolete technique which is prone to errors and crashes and is by no means recommended to be used in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The [`$.watch`](https://github.com/darcyclarke/Watch.js) plugin can do this:

```
$('.div1').watch('display', function() {
    var display = ($(this).css('display') === 'grid' ? 'none' : 'block');

    $('.div2').css('display', display);
});
```

Unlike the `setInterval` method, here's what the library does (from the github page):

> This plugin lets you listen for when a CSS property, or properties, changes on element. It utilizes Mutation Observers to mimic the `DOMAttrModified` (Mutation Events API) and `propertychange` (Internet Explorer) events.

Be aware that your original code uses `$('div2')` instead of `$('.div2')` and will only match elements that look like this: `<div2>foo</div2>`. I've changed it to a class in my example.

Comment: I don't understand this.  what does this do exactly?

Comment: @Dr.Donnaloia It uses mutation observers if they're available and if they're not it uses IEs propertchange event. It's just an already built wheel made so you don't have to.

Comment: so the watch function above is just checking for any property changes? and then if there's a change, (display, display)?

Comment: @Dr.Donnaloia correct. Thus is way better than constantly checking.

Comment: And in case you're wondering about the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Will you help me with this codepen example so I can understand? http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/YPrvod

Comment: so I want to change the font color of "hello" when clicking button, and then change the font color of "goodbye", whenever the "hello" color is changed.

Comment: You're going very wrong with this then. Use the .data() function to set a state and invert it when you click it

Comment: this is strictly an example for the sake of learning, I understand that this is not an efficient way to change font color!  Again, I am just trying to learn how the code you pasted above works.