# Any ways to detect CSS changing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this tags:

```
<div>
   <h1>
   </h1>
</div>
```

Then I have a javascript lib that changes font-size of the `<div>` tag, but `<h1>` has its own CSS. Then text in `<h1>` does not change. I just want resizing font-size of `<div>` affecting `<h1>`. I cannot change the javascript lib nor the html structure. So, I think that it would be good to have something like

```
$('div').bind('css-change', function (){ 
    $('h1').css('fontSize',$('div')Text.css('fontSize'));
})
```

Any ways to have something like .bind('css-change') ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery

Comment: Simply having a static `h1 {font-size:1em}` in the stylesheet won't work?

Comment: As @dotweb said , this is duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery . And the answer is in there.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is no event that is triggered on css change...
Why not change the css of the `<h1>` via JS and set it to inherit the font-size?

```
$('h1').css('fontSize','inherit');
```

Comment: Kinda help, but it does not completely help. The thing is that I still need the initial 'font-size' of H1 as 'default' font-size. If div is being resized, h1 will can have 'inherit', but not before that.

Comment: So, I presume there is a function that does the resizing (or at least a kind of "onresize event" if resizing is triggered by the user) - can't you just set the font-size to inherit as soon as this function/event is being executed?

Comment: sorry for late reply, we thought about that too. Unfortunately my team don't want to edit 3rd-party code (in case we have to update it in future). So, if you know how to 'hook' to particular method like the concept of aspect programming, that would be perfect.

Comment: @SurasinTancharoen could you name that 3rd party plugin please?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has implemented in version 1.4.3: [cssHooks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/)

```
$.cssHooks["someCSSProp"] = {
    get: function( elem, computed, extra ) {
      // handle getting the CSS property
    },
    set: function( elem, value ) {
      // handle setting the CSS value
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Armin, I fear that either this is not helpful in this context, or I misunderstood the use of cssHooks... :)

Comment: No, you are right! This isn't helpful in this context! I have misunderstood the question.