# Fade Out an HTML Element That is Being "Hidden" by a CSS Class

Tags: jquery, html, css

There are times when it's useful to hide certain HTML elements on your page by adding a CSS class, which sets `display: none`. Please take a look at this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sikusikucom/afTdk/).

```
<!-- HTML -->
<a id="toggle-a" href="javascript:void(0);">Hide A</a>
<p id="p-a">A</p>

/* CSS */
.hide {
  display: none;
}

/* jQuery */
$("#toggle-a").click(function() {
  $("#p-a").addClass("hide");
});
```

Is there a way to fade out / animate `p#a` when we apply `.hide` to it?

**EDIT**:
Sorry if my previous question wasn't clear. I am interested in the following: can I trigger `.fadeOut()` upon a property change on the CSS level? In the example above, it is when `p#a`'s `display` *is changing* from non-`none` to `none`? Note that the `display` property was changed to `none` by a different script by applying a class named `hide` to it.

Comment: You're asking if there's a way to [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) something with jQuery?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/afTdk/1/ or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/afTdk/2/) (`fadeIn` and `fadeOut`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty basic jQuery, fading stuff in or out. You can use [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) here:

```
$("#toggle-a").click(function() {
    $("#p-a").fadeToggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/afTdk/4/

Since only javascript can actually change the class, there's not much point in attaching some separate listener for the class change.

Comment: Thanks for the input. @Madmartigan, is there a way in jQuery to "monitor" when there is a change in a CSS property e.g. from `display: block` to `display: none`?

Comment: You mean to listen for a change in *any* property? I'm not sure exactly, I think you'd be better off figuring out exactly what you're trying to accomplish. For your example I think you can use `if($("element").css('display') === 'block')`. Maybe something with `getComputedStyle`. I guess you could wrap that in a `setTimeout` but it seems like a waste.

Comment: Yes, a listener for *any* property change. Maybe a default jQuery method or any plugin e.g. `$('#p-a').onCSSChange( /* callback */ );` which will be fired every time there is a CSS change for `p#a`, regardless who triggered the change.

Comment: After thinking about this further, I think I might have been looking for something not available in jQuery right now. Hey, maybe this can be a future request for jQuery! :)

Comment: Weird that your comment above got a random drive-by upvote the second you posted it? This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery

Comment: I just +1 your previous comment (after the second you added, I think), which hopefully isn't random / weird: your comment helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: No I just thought it was random that some third party UV'd your prev comment the second it was posted (wasn't me). Anyways, I doubt they'd put this in jQuery core because I really don't see a general use case for it. If you can provide a real-life reason to use this, I'd consider re-posting (if the link I provided didn't help). Programmers will always try to provide the shorter, faster, easier, efficient way to get something done, and your example was too specific.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQuery `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` functions. For example:

```
$("#toggle-a").click(function() {
  $("#p-a").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
$("#toggle-a").click(function() {
    $("#p-a").animate({'marginLeft':'200px'}, function() {
       $(this).addClass('hide');
    });
});
```

You can read [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) about jquery animation and also don't forget to take a look at function called "callback" (complete parameter)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @Madmartigan, I think I was looking for something currently is not available in jQuery. There is no way for jQuery to automatically monitor *any* CSS changes that happen on a particular HTML element; you basically need to do it rather "manually e.g. `if($("element").css('display') === 'block')`.

Maybe this can be a future request for jQuery? :)