# JQuery Detect class changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a plugin that added a class `open` to `.slide-out-div` when opened.

So I am trying to change some css if the open is detected.

What I need to do is

```
IF

$('.slide-out-div **open**') IS Detected then

$('.otherDiv').css('top','0px');
```

Not sure how to put this together...

Comment: when is the class getting added?

Comment: @MildFuzz. I guess he doesn't control it, it's a plugin...

Comment: What plugin are you using? It sounds like a better plan to work the solution into the used script.

Comment: also, the plugin author might have added custom events. Worth checking out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Fire event if CSS class changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no event of `class-added`, you will need to track it yourself...

It can be done with an infinite loop with `setTimeout` to check if the class has changed.

```
function checkForChanges()
{
    if ($('.slide-out-div').hasClass('open'))
        $('.otherDiv').css('top','0px');
    else
        setTimeout(checkForChanges, 500);
}
```

You can call the function when you want, or onDOM ready:

```
$(checkForChanges);
```

Comment: This will work. However, it's a very dirty approach if you ask me.

Comment: It seems a working solution can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1397500/439944

Comment: @sieppl. `mutation events` are **deprecated** as they have huge performance impact.

Comment: @gdoron. +1 for mentioning this.

Comment: @gdoron - They aren't deprecated! (check MDN) the OLD ones are, the mutation observer is the new way of detecting changes. here's how - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14570614/104380

Comment: Done is better than perfect. +1

Comment: Always prefer a setInterval solution over setTimeout when you use this kind of recursion. Cause your stack can endless grow.

Comment: @Healkiss it is exactly the same. The stack won't endless grow.

Comment: @vsync you are aware your comment was written to years after the answer was given, right...? Anyway, the new mutation events have limited support. (For future readers)

Comment: @gdoron You make me review my basics. Thanks, you're right.

Comment: @Healkiss it's funny how stuff work at stack overflow. People down vote without knowing the basics... well that's the internet, you can love it or hate it, but that's what it is.

Comment: @gdoron. First, i beg your pardon. I didn't down vote for this in particular. It's a dirty solution. Many other, like DOMSubtreeModified, overridding addClass are prettiest solutions. In term of performance. Don't be offended." I " think we should avoid setInterval and SetTimeout when possible. Especially in this case where you should low the interval to the minimum to be reactive.

Comment: @Healkiss I didn't got offended, but if you want both performance and all browsers support, this is the best solution. Mutation events(at least when this answer was given, were deprecated and **huge** bad performance impact, I stopped following its state so I don't know how it's today)

Answer (score 32):

The question's a bit old, but since I came across while looking for a similar problem, thought I'd share the solution I went with here - [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

In your case, I'd create a mutation observer

```
var mut = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, mut){
  // if attribute changed === 'class' && 'open' has been added, add css to 'otherDiv'
});
mut.observe(document.querySelector(".slide-out-div"),{
  'attributes': true
});
```

The function in mutation observer is called any time an attribute of .slide-out-div is changed, so need to verify the actual change before acting.

More details here on [Mozilla's documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: This looks like a great approach, but should be noted that it doesn't appear to have support in IE10 and older.

Comment: This suggestion is so good because native :) Thanks your share.

Comment: Mutation Observer is an Awesome feature. :) Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [attrchange jQuery plugin](http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/). The main function of the plugin is to bind a listener function on attribute change of HTML elements.

Code sample:

```
$("#myDiv").attrchange({
    trackValues: true, // set to true so that the event object is updated with old & new values
    callback: function(evnt) {
        if(evnt.attributeName == "class") { // which attribute you want to watch for changes
            if(evnt.newValue.search(/open/i) == -1) { // "open" is the class name you search for inside "class" attribute

                // your code to execute goes here...
            }
        }
    }
});
```