# jquery event check - if there's changes in selector css (display block / none)

Tags: jquery, css

This is quite hard to explain....

I'm using a framework that displays statusbar (display: none/block) after the page have been loaded (javascript).

Is there a way to "live" check if there's changes in that specific selector?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking to be triggered when css property change, take a look at this similar question : [Event detect when css property changed using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery).

The posted solution propose to use a trigger on "DOMAttrModified". But be careful if this answer fit your needs about browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($("#yourElement").is(":visible")) {
    //is visible
  }
  else {
    //none
  }
});
```