# How to get width of a Progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, html5-canvas

I have a file upload progress bar but it doesn't show the progress value I inspected it and i saw that its width attribute is progressing and the progress bar is dynamically generated and after upload it disappears:

```
<div id="pic-progress-wrap" class="progress-wrap"></div> this is the  only code  can see when it is not uploading
```

and in uploading

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 23%;"></div></div>
```

this code can be seen it generated dynamically.

I want to get the width attribute value out and show it inside a span.

Comment: You should [add an event listener on `DOMAttrModified`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery) or use jQuery [*attrchange* plugin](http://meetselva.github.io/attrchange/) to bind a listener function on attribute change of an element.

Comment: if you only want to get width value then use: document.getElementById("abc").children[0].style.width   where abc is parent div id