# How to trigger JavaScript function when div display none?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one `<div>` which has a property `display:none` by default if some message i want to show to user then i am using this div. I dont want to allow user to do any action once this div displayed.

There is a lots of way user can do that div `display:none` so i want to trigger function on `display:none` of this `<div>`

But i dont know how to get event so that i can come to know about display property of the div

Comment: what is your problem, your are just saying `div` `display:none`, I'm not getting, can someone explain?

Comment: i want to trigger one function if div diplay:none proprty is changed

Comment: see this example : http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: There is no event for this. You can check the `display` property of the element in your functions. Something like `if ($('#elem').is(':hidden')) {  }`

Comment: @Mritunjay javascript event on css style change from block to none

Comment: Another related question: [Event detect when css property changed using Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery)

Comment: Try this code `if (($("#Div").css("display"))=="block") {  }` Hope this may useful