# Hide and show element in sync with another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I had two `<div>` elements like so:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
<!-- Other content here -->
<div class="popup"></div>
```

When `div.popup` has `display: block` I would like `div.overlay` to also have `display: block` and likewise for `display: none;`

Instead of using an if statement to check whether `div.popup` if visible, I would like to have something like an event handler.

How would I do this using jQuery? Thanks.

Comment: _"One thing I forgot to mention I would like it to check automatically, instead of doing this with an if statement I would like something like an event handler."_ Can include how is `display` property for `.popup` is changed at `js` , `css` at Question ? What is `<!-- Other content here -->` at `html` ?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery

Comment: Well? Mind showing some jQuery you currently have? P.S: why don't you simply place your popup inside overlay?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below. Hope this will help you.

```
setInterval(function() { 
    if($('div.popup').is(':visible')) {
        $('div.overlay').show();
    } else {
        $('div.overlay').hide();
    }
}, 20);
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention I would like it to check automatically, instead of doing this with an if statement I would like something like an event handler.

Comment: You can use `setInterval` to do this repeatedly after an interval. See updated answer. @PavSidhu

Comment: Really bad idea to run a setInterval to check for elements visibility.