# How detect the browser has finished changing an element's display?

Tags: javascript

I've found if I have an element of `display: none` and I set it to "block", many browsers will have a slight delay before the element has an actual size `console.log(element.offsetWidth === 0)`.

I've always created an interval or timeout checked that keeps polling until it has a size. But this is a hack.

Is there an actual event or some way to tell the browser to do something only when it has finished giving it display and layout?

Comment: Does this resolve your issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery

Comment: works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/grfsf6mb/1/

Comment: The element should be re-rendered on the next tick. For information on how to force a re-render, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes.

Comment: @torazaburo take a look at https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a accessing certain style attributes is synchronous (including `offsetWidth` so there should not be a need to use setTimeout).

Comment: @mguimard No. That event has been deprecated and is being removed from browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Comment: @RolandStarke in some versions of IE and Firefox, I have found that an immediate check can sometimes return 0 unless you do a setTimeout