# Delegating an "if" to the document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element which dynamically gets a "display:block". Now when this happens I’d like to add a class to another element. I know I have to delegate the code below somehow to the document. But I have no idea how to do this.

```
if ($(".status").css("display") == "block" ){
  $("#Menu").addClass("reduced");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/1397251/2119863

Comment: Note that Mutation Events are now deprecated in favour of [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: Although it's not been updated for a while, the [Mutation-summary](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary) library may well be your best way ahead on this.

Comment: Do you have access to the function where "an element dynamically get a display:block;"? If so, just add `$("#Menu").addClass("reduced");` in that function. Or do you mean it is added before DOM load?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: The proposed post "Event detect …" solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

It should be as follows:

```
if ($(".status").attr("display") == "block" ){
   $("#Menu").addClass("reduced");
}
```

**To get any css attribute use .attr()**

Comment: May i know why i got minus vote..